# Swiper - Display the number of the current slides in view

Tags: pagination, grid, swiper.js

I am using Swiper and the grid format to display 12 slides at a time. I would like pagination to display the number of slides on one page vs the number of pages. For example, let's say I have 36 slides. 12 display on each page. I would like the pagination to read "slides 13-24" instead of "page 2/3."

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10bMF.png)

I have been using Swiper's documentation to try and figure this out, but I'm not having any luck. I haven't found any examples that are similar to my issue either.

Comment: It is problematic because of the math of this. By `formatFractionCurrent` you can format the Fraction maybe (But you should create the math by yourself).